# postgresql cannot insert data to newly added column

Tags: postgresql

In postgresql I have a table which I need to add a new column. the original table ddl is belowing:

```
CREATE TABLE survey.survey_response (
id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
survey_id uuid NOT NULL,
survey_question_id uuid NULL,
user_id varchar(256) NULL,
device_id varchar(256) NULL,
user_country varchar(100) NULL,
client_type varchar(100) NULL,
product_version varchar(100) NULL,
answer text NULL,
response_date timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
survey_category varchar(100) NULL,
tags varchar(250) NULL,
tracking_id uuid NULL,
CONSTRAINT survey_response_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
) ;
```

Then I alter the table to add a new column:

```
alter table survey.survey_response add column system_tags varchar(30) ;
```

But after that I found my instert statement cannot make change to this new column, for all the original columns it works fine:

```
INSERT INTO survey.survey_response
(id, survey_id, user_id,  tags, system_tags)
VALUES(uuid_generate_v4(), uuid_generate_v4(),'1123','dsfsd', 'dsfsd');

select * from survey.survey_response where user_id = '1123';
```

The "tags" columns contains inserted value, however, system_tags keeps null.

I tested the above scenario in my local postgreSQL 9.6,  any ideas about this strange behavior?  Thanks a lot

-----------------update----------

I found this survey.survey_response table has been partitioning based on month, So my inserted record will also be displayed in survey.survey_response_y2017m12. but the new system_tags column is also NULL

```
CREATE TABLE survey.survey_response_y2017m12 (
id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
survey_id uuid NOT NULL,
survey_question_id uuid NULL,
user_id varchar(256) NULL,
device_id varchar(256) NULL,
user_country varchar(100) NULL,
client_type varchar(100) NULL,
product_version varchar(100) NULL,
answer text NULL,
response_date timestamptz NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
survey_category varchar(100) NULL,
tags varchar(250) NULL,
tracking_id uuid NULL,
system_tags varchar(30) NULL,
CONSTRAINT survey_response_y2017m12_response_date_check CHECK (((response_date >= '2017-12-01'::date) AND (response_date < '2018-01-01'::date)))
)
INHERITS (survey.survey_response)
WITH (
OIDS=FALSE
```

) ;

If I run the same scenario in a non-partition table then the insert works fine.

So do I need any special settings for alter table for partition table?

Comment: This sounds fishy to me.  Is there any sort of error/warning feedback when you do that insert?  It doesn't sound at all right that Postgres would not insert into a column and remain silent about that.

Comment: You for sure have pgAdmin or any other database tool like phpstorm. Try to run the insert sql there. Does it work or do you get an error ?

Comment: yes, I have tried in pgAdmin and dbeaver, no errors, all the other column contents are inserted.

Comment: If you do it in pgAdmin has it inserted the correct values ?

Comment: all the original columns updated, the new one keeps null. However I found this table is a partition table, I updated my descripton for it. is it helpful to find the root cause for it?

Comment: Is there any triggers on `survey.survey_response` table?

Comment: Right. There is probably something fishy with the triggers used to redirect the insert (if inheritance partitioning is used).

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but you need to drop and create again the RULE to fix the issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).